# ZigBee Mesh VS DigiMesh

Tags: xbee, zigbee, mesh-network

Which is better, ZigBee Mesh (Series 2) or DigiMesh (Series 1)?

I have already read *[Wireless Mesh Networking, ZigBee vs. DigiMesh](http://www.digi.com/pdf/wp_zigbeevsdigimesh.pdf)* (PDF format), but I noted there are many advantages of using DigiMesh, instead, I expected to read that Series 2 is better than Series 1 for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mesh networking, which require a lot of ZigBee devices, it's advisable to use a ZigBee mesh. It requires lower power and can talk to any ZigBee device other that not come from Digi. Digi mesh is actually an extension for XBee series 1 with capability for mesh networking and cannot talk to any other Digi devices (as far as I know). The main purpose of XBee Series 1 is to doing point-to-point communication.

Answer (score 3):

ZigBee is a standard protocol supported by multiple vendors.  DigiMesh is specific to XBee modules, and is available on various radios (2.4GHz, 900MHz, 868MHz).

In ZigBee, you have a single coordinator for the network, router devices that are always on, and end devices that can sleep to conserve power.

In DigiMesh, all devices are routers that can sleep to conserve power.

The White Paper that you linked to is the best summary of the differences between the two, and advantages of each.

Comment: Do you have further information about the DIGIMesh protocol?

Answer (score 0):

ZigBee Mesh (Series 2) is better compared to DigiMesh (Series 1). You can find more at the [ZigBee Alliance home page](http://www.zigbee.org).